# Debug C++ with gdb: how to check the value of std::vector -- passed in function

Tags: c++, gdb

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

void testConst(std::vector<std::string> v1)
{
   std::string& a = v1[0];
   std::cout << a << "\n";
   return;
}

int main()
{
   std::string x1 = "abc";
   std::string x2 = "def";
   std::vector<std::string> v1;
   v1.push_back(x1);
   v1.push_back(x2);

   testConst(v1);

   return 0;
}
```

gdb:

```
b main.cpp:21
run
p *(v1._M_impl._M_start)
b main.cpp:10
c
p *(v1._M_impl._M_start)
```

In line 21, I can get correct v1[0], which is "abc";
In line 10, I can't get correct v1[0];

Question: within gdb, how can get correct v1[0] in line 10?

Environment: Red Hat Linux environment.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> within gdb, how can get correct v1[0] in line 10?

You are passing `v1` variable by value in `testConst` function.
In line 10 (`return` statement), this variable is going out of scope and thus getting destroyed. That's why you can't reliably print values of `v1`.

Probably you wanted to pass `v1` by reference like this:

```
void testConst(std::vector<std::string>& v1)
```

With this modification `v1[0]` should be printed well.